# Datetime range using between for switch case data search

Tags: php

I've been trying to make this query condition work. I'm making a Datatable search using PHP.

The agent, ID, and number could be search properly but when the datetime range is involved, the datetime is not working.

Please help. Thank you.

Here is the code:

````
  
  $name = "";
  $id = "";
  $phone = "";
 
  
  
  $queryCondition = "";
  if(!empty($_POST["search"])) {
    foreach($_POST["search"] as $k=>$v){
      if(!empty($v)) {

        $queryCases = array("datetime","name","id","phone");
        if(in_array($k,$queryCases)) {
          if(!empty($queryCondition)) {
            $queryCondition .= " AND ";
          } else {
            $queryCondition .= " WHERE ";
          }
        }
        switch($k) {
          case "datetime":
          $date_from=$_POST[date_from];
          $date_to=$_POST[date_to];
          $queryCondition .= "datetime BETWEEN '" . $date_from . "' AND '" . $date_to . "' ";
          break;
          case "agent":
            $name = $v;
            $queryCondition .= "name LIKE '" . $v . "%'";
            break;
          case "id":
            $id_yoda = $v;
            $queryCondition .= "id LIKE '" . $v . "%'";
            break;
          case "phone":
            $po_phone = $v;
            $queryCondition .= "phone LIKE '" . $v . "%'";
            break;
          
        }
      }
    }
  }
  $orderby = "ORDER BY id desc"; 
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM datatable" . $queryCondition;
  $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);         
  


?>```
````

Comment: I would recommend you to `var_dump($sql)` at the end to investigate how your SQL query looks like. Perhaps you have some kind of SQL editor in your database admin tool where you can put your SQL query and see if there are any syntax errors or similar...

Comment: I think the query is correct because i tried it already. When i put the switch case, that's where the problem started.